# Fork(); method in C

Tags: c, linux, fork

I'm taking an operating systems class and we're learning about forking. I'm having a bit of trouble with one particular example. I can't find anything online that specifically explains what I need. Hopefully someone here can help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    pid_t pid1, pid2, pid3;
    pid1=0, pid2=0, pid3=0;
    pid1= fork();
    if(pid1==0){
        pid2=fork();
        pid3=fork();
    } else {
        pid3=fork();
        if(pid3==0) {
            pid2=fork();
        }
        if((pid1 == 0)&&(pid2 == 0))
            printf("Level 1\n");
        if(pid1 !=0)
            printf("Level 2\n");
        if(pid2 !=0)
           printf("Level 3\n");
        if(pid3 !=0)
           printf("Level 4\n");
       return 0;
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain this to me? I understand that the processes are running parallel and that it's unsure which one will be running first. My problem is understanding the values after each fork.

So when the first fork returns there are now 2 processes, the Parent and the Child. The child gets all the contents of the Parent. So parent had pid1, pid2, pid3 = 0 right? and the child had the same? I have a the output of the program. If i just knew what happened exactly after the first fork i think I can work out the rest.

Comment: What values? The PIDs?

Comment: 1) C does not support _methods_, but only _functions_. 2) Format your code! This is a mess. 3) The signature of `main` is wrong. 4) You did not find the manpage of `fork`? 5) What do you mean with "running first"? Think about what "parallel running" implies.

Comment: Are you asking what does `fork()` return? Please clarify your question.

Comment: Remove the **put on hold**. After the last edit of the OP I think the question is clear.

Comment: Please remove the on hold

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me name the forks:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    pid_t pid1, pid2, pid3;
    pid1=0, pid2=0, pid3=0;
    pid1= fork(); /* A */
    if(pid1==0){
        pid2=fork(); /* B */
        pid3=fork(); /* C */
    } else {
        pid3=fork(); /* D */
        if(pid3==0) {
            pid2=fork(); /* E */
        }
        if((pid1 == 0)&&(pid2 == 0))
            printf("Level 1\n");
        if(pid1 !=0)
            printf("Level 2\n");
        if(pid2 !=0)
           printf("Level 3\n");
        if(pid3 !=0)
           printf("Level 4\n");
       return 0;
    }
}
```

Then, the execution will be:

```
----A----D--------- (pid1!=0, pid2==0(as initialized), pid3!=0, print "Level 2" and "Level 4")
    |    |
    |    +----E---- (pid1!=0, pid2!=0, pid3==0, print "Level 2" and "Level 3")
    |         |
    |         +---- (pid1!=0, pid2==0, pid3==0, print "Level 2")
    |
    +----B----C---- (pid1==0, pid2!=0, pid3!=0, print nothing)
         |    |
         |    +---- (pid1==0, pid2==0, pid3==0, print nothing)
         |
         +----C---- (pid1==0, pid2==0, pid3!=0, print nothing)
              |
              +---- (pid1==0, pid2==0, pid3==0, print nothing)
```

Comment: Could I pm you to explain further if you have time?http://collabedit.com/hmjyx

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to guess which part needs explaining, but as a basic overview, `fork()` duplicates the current process as a "child."  The original (parent) process gets a return value equal to the child's process ID from the operating system or `-1` if the call fails.  The child, starting at the same position in the code, gets a return value of `0`, because it doesn't have a child.

The operating system has full control of scheduling the processes, so which one runs when is impossible to guess in advance, but the process ID can be used to determine the state of children.

The code is pretty abstract and doesn't really serve a non-example purpose.  But since it calls `fork()` five times, it will be called once by the main process, once *each* by the parent and child (total of twice), once each by the parent, children, and grandchild (four times), and so forth.  Those should correlate with the number of times the `Level` messages are issued.